# Antivirus for netbooks: AVG, GData, or something else?

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus

I have a HP Mini 110 running Windows 7 32 bits (RAM 1 GB, HD 150 GB, CPU Intel N270 1.60 GHz).
When I bough it, I was suggested to use AVG, or GData. Which one do you suggest? Are there other alternatives?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/security_essentials/) is free, good, lightweight. I recommend it for anything from a netbook to an 8-core workstation.

Comment: All of the above.  Use MSE!  Hell, it pulls new definitions through Windows Update!

Comment: @Shinrai If it updates through Windows Update, how often does it update?

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/177291/ms-security-essentials-does-not-update-automatically

Comment: @mklhmnn Thanks for the info link. So, it would seem MSE does not update nearly as often as other anti-virus manufacturers recommend. Even the free version of Avast! Antivirus checks for updates every 4 hours and does indeed update its virus definitions several times a day. (Although TBH I do wonder how often this needs to happen for the average user, but you never know!)

Answer (score 2):

A no hassle option is Microsoft security essentials.

Answer (score 1):

I love Kaspersky.

Kaspersky Antivirus Netbook Edition should be lightweight and would run on your system fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of [Avast (Free)](http://www.avast.com/free-antivirus-download). Much better than AVG IMHO (which slowed my machine, internet connection and appeared to conflict with ZoneAlarm firewall)

Answer (score 0):

Avira Antivir is pretty lightweith too. The paid version has more features but the free version is sufficient if you can tolerate the "If you like it, buy the paid version"-popup that is shown after the daily definitions update.
http://www.free-av.com/en/download/index.html