# MS Security Essentials does not update automatically

Tags: updates, ms-security-essentials

I've installed Microsoft Security Essentials and my Windows XP Professional SP3 and it does not seem to install update signatures multiple times a day as I'm used to from other virus scanning tools. The signatures were two days old when I updated it manually.

My user account is a limited one, running [surun](http://kay-bruns.de/wp/software/surun/) if that might matter. But if I double click the MSSE tray icon and click the Update button myself, it updates, so I guess it can't be a permission problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using MSE for a while now, and it does not update multiple times a day. 
It does update every few days though.

If your computer is set to automatically install recommended updates, then the updates will come even through Windows Update. (Make sure to have Microsoft update enabled).

Comment: Do they get installed automatically though? I keep seeing definitions released daily but not checked for "install automatically"; they're always under "optional updates". Is there a way to force them to always download automatically?

Comment: Mine come in with normal Windows updates. I also have Microsoft Update enabled so the updates for MSE are installed regularly with other stuff for Windows